# How to see portlet configuration page in Liferay?

Tags: java, jsp, liferay, liferay-ide

When creating portlet in Liferay IDE, I have configured it to have Liferay's configuration mode. In response, the wizart created JSP file with the following text:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/portlet_2_0" prefix="portlet" %>

<portlet:defineObjects />

This is the <b>MyPortlet</b> portlet in Config mode.
```

How to call this page from Liferay to see this text? When clicking wrench icon and selecting `Configuration` I see nothing similar.

**UPDATE**

Path is set correctly because it was set by wizard.

The question is how to call this JSP from web interface by a mouse?

Answer (score 1):

Usually the problem is that the path to the configuration jsp is not properly set.

In `portlet.xml`

Add the following:

```xml
<init-param>
    <name>config-template</name>
    <value>/path/to/configuration.jsp</value>
</init-param>
```

as a child of the `<portlet>` element that corresponds to the portlet you're trying to modify.

Your final `portlet.xml` should look something like:

```xml
<portlet-app>
    <portlet>
        <portlet-name>my-portlet</portlet-name>
        <display-name>My Portlet</display-name>
        <portlet-class>com.liferay.portlet.StrutsPortlet</portlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <name>config-template</name>
            <value>/path/to/configuration.jsp</value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <name>view-action</name>
            <value>/my_portlet/view</value>
        </init-param>
        <expiration-cache>0</expiration-cache>
        <supports>
            <mime-type>text/html</mime-type>
        </supports>
    </portlet>
</portlet-app>
```

Answer (score 1):

From the wiki (no shame here though, took me a very long time to find it):

[Add Config Page to Plugin Portlet](http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Add+Config+Page+to+Plugin+Portlet) <- get more info here

liferay-portlet.xml->

```
    <portlet>
      <portlet-name>configuration-example</portlet-name>
      <icon>/icon.png</icon> 
      <configuration-action-class>com.sample.jsp.action.ConfigurationActionImpl</configuration-action-class> 
      <instanceable>true</instanceable> 
      <header-portlet-css>/css/test.css</header-portlet-css> 
      <footer-portlet-javascript>/js/test.js</footer-portlet-javascript> 
    </portlet>
```

ConfigurationActionImpl.java (or your class)->

```
    public class ConfigurationActionImpl implements ConfigurationAction {
        public void processAction(PortletConfig config, ActionRequest actionRequest, ActionResponse actionResponse) throws Exception { 

          String portletResource = ParamUtil.getString(actionRequest, "portletResource"); 

          PortletPreferences prefs = PortletPreferencesFactoryUtil.getPortletSetup(actionRequest, portletResource); 

          //Read, validate, and then set form parameters as portlet preferences

          prefs.store();

          SessionMessages.add(actionRequest, portletConfig.getPortletName() + ".doConfigure");
        }
        public String render(PortletConfig config, RenderRequest renderRequest, RenderResponse renderResponse) throws Exception { 

        return "/configuration.jsp";
        }
    }
```

Configuration.jsp

```
    <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/portlet" prefix="portlet" %>
    <%@ taglib uri="http://liferay.com/tld/portlet" prefix="liferay-portlet" %>

    <portlet:defineObjects />

    <form action="<liferay-portlet:actionURL portletConfiguration="true" />" method="post" name="<portlet:namespace />fm"> <input name="<portlet:namespace /><%=Constants.CMD%>" type="hidden" value="<%=Constants.UPDATE%>" /> 

    Type: <select name="<portlet:namespace />type"> <option value="casual">Casual</option> <option value="formal">Formal</option> </select> <br/>

    <input type="button" value="Save" onClick="submitForm(document.<portlet:namespace />fm);" /> </form>
```

"Note the portletConfiguration attribute in the liferay-portlet:actionURL tag."